# load div from page.. from the href of class

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, colorbox, html-content-extraction

my page has got a lot of div's with `<a href>`'s to open modalboxes (colorbox). The pages that these links open got an `id="mainColumn"`. Content need only to be loaded from this id.

```
<div>                       
<a href="includes/page_1.html" class="pop"></a>
</div>

<div>                       
<a href="includes/page_2.html" class="pop"></a>
</div>

<div>                       
<a href="includes/page_3.html" class="pop"></a>
</div>


 $(".pop").colorbox({
    href: $(".pop").attr('href') + " #mainColumn"
    });
```

The href's of al of the `<a>`'s change into the first one...

So 
includes/page_3.html changes into includes/page_1.html
or in other words: All of the modalboxes show the same content...

`$(this)` gives me content undefined

any help would appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside of the options for colorbox you have referenced `$(".pop").attr('href')` which get `href` attribute of the *first* `.pop` element. You have to wrap it into calling of `each` method.

```
$(".pop").each(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  el.colorbox({
    href: el.attr('href') + " #mainColumn"
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry got distracted.. food on the table :P